# Laravel Error : Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5.3

I don't know what I have done with my Laravel 5.3 Project but I have this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel
>   does not exist in 
>   C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:729
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(729):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Kernel') #1
>   C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(608):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Http\Kernel') #2
>   C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(564):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\Http\Kernel', Array) #3
>   C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(709):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->makeWith('App\Http\Kernel', Array)
>   4 C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(248):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->makeWith('App\Http\Kernel',
>   Array) #5 C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\f in
>   C:\laragon\www\BookTime\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 729

OS : Windows 10
Localhost : Laragon
PHP Version : 5.6.4

That's my package.json

```
   {  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
  }
}
```

My providers in  app.php

[

```
        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [
        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    ],
```

How can I resolve this problem please ?

Comment: provide more info about your setup. Which OS - which php version - are you running laravel behind a virtual host or in a subdirectory? Apache or nginx? Do you have the permissions?

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @ArigiWiratama I already try it, and I have the same error :x

Comment: Problems like this are often caused by .env variables with spaces in it.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, any solution so far?

Comment: Check this link: github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6175 Hope for somebody it will help

Answer (score 9):

This is normally solved by doing this:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: When I do this "php artisan config:clear " I have the error display in my cmd

Comment: @ArigiWiratama, Sletheren In my first post I mentionned my error

Comment: try running `composer update` first then `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: what is the result of these commands? are they running correctly?

Comment: what was the last changes u did before the project goes down?

Comment: Good question, I don't really remember, but I was trying to install gulp =>npm install –global gulp-cli

Comment: What was the solutions finally?

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6175
Hope for somebody it will help

Comment: I think this is wrong, i get `There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace.` in Laravel 8.61