# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Kernel does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, laravel-8

I have a live website that was working fine a couple of days ago but suddenly began to show this error!

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Kernel does not exist in /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877
```

**Here is the full Stack trace that I get when I view the error_log file**

```
[08-Dec-2021 22:05:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Kernel does not exist in /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(877): ReflectionClass->__construct('Kernel')
    #1 /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(758): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Kernel')
    #2 /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(851): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Kernel', Array, true)
    #3 /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(694): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('Kernel', Array)
    #4 /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(836): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Kerne in /home/obhv9r1r3cc9/assign_away_laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 879
```

I have gone through various answers here but have not been able to fix this issue.

Any ideas on how that issue can be resolved?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45354086/3864485)

Comment: I tried that. The irony is it works fine on localhost but when I upload the code on the live server then it starts to throw the errr.

Comment: Did you tried the same solution on the machine online ?

Comment: I don't have the composer available on the serve.
I ran the commands and reuploaded the code to server

Comment: You should get an access on webroot to run theses commands on your server online.

Comment: You can't properly run Laravel without Composer.